# Is it possible to contain a left or right swipe to a pre-defined area?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Is it possible to only allow swipes in certain area's of the screen?  For example, I have a count down timer, and to increase it or decrease it, I would like to swipe left or right over the time to increase or decrease the value.  Is this possible? or are UISwipGestureRecogniser's only screen specific?

Thanks again!

-PaulS.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to detect a gesture bounded to a specific view with UISwipeGestureRecognizer and then attach the consequent logic to it, like

```
 CGPoint point = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:MyView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to make swiping work in a predefine UIView.  Make sure you make an IBOutlet for your view and Swip Gestures:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface home_1_ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

//UISwipeGestureRecognizer properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizerRight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizerLeft;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewGestureCountDown;

@end
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *left = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeleft:)];
    [left setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [viewGestureCountDown addGestureRecognizer:left];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *right = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwiperight:)];    
    [right setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [viewGestureCountDown addGestureRecognizer:right];
}


- (void)oneFingerSwipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
    NSLog(@"You swiped Left");
}

- (void)oneFingerSwiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{ 
    NSLog(@"You swiped Right");
}
```

Thanks to those that helped come up with this.  Works perfect.

-PaulS.